# Jsoup - Parsing Selected Elements

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I need to parse the below HTML content using Jsoup parser. 
The requirement is to eliminate a few tags and get the below output.
I am not able to get the desired output with the below code

Input :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type=\ "text/css\">
    body {
      font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }
    
    tr {
      font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>hello,<br>&nbsp;<br>We need to dispatch the below documents to you. Thanks for your cooperation.<br><br>Best Regards</p><br>
  <img id=\ "logo_GMALE.png\" alt=\ "logo GMALE\" src=\ "https://www.GMALE.ch/logo.png\">

  <br><b>Test abc xyz</b><br><br>T +91 98 471 <br>

  <a href=\ "mailto:output.test@GMALE.in\">output.test@GMALE.in</a><br><br><b>Département Team</b><br><br><b>GMALE Assurances</b><br>StreetName 2<br>Postbox 2100<br>Country<br><br>GMALE.ch<br><br>This is a private email contents.<br><br>This e-mail transmission
  is intended for the named addressee(s) only. Its contents are private, confidential and protected from disclosure and should not be read, copied or disclosed by any other person. If you are not the intended recipient, we kindly ask you to notify the
  sender immediately and to delete this e-mail.<br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```html
<p>hello,<br>&nbsp;<br>We need to dispatch the below documents to you. Thanks for your cooperation.<br><br>Best Regards</p><br>

<br><b>Test abc xyz</b><br><br>T +91 98 471 <br>
```

Code done so far is below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);       
List<Node> childNodes = doc.select("body").get(0).childNodes();
System.out.println("Elements : " + childNodes);
StringBuilder  finalContent = new StringBuilder();
for (Node node : childNodes) {
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element subElement = (Element) node;
        if (!subElement.tagName().equals("img")) {
            finalContent.append(subElement);
        }
    } else {
        TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
        if(!textNode.getWholeText().startsWith("<a")) {
            finalContent.append(textNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be defined as follows: parse `body` of following HTML and extract all data until reaching `<a href=\ "mailto:output.test@GMALE.in\">`. If you look at your problem from this angle you can try following approach:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
final Elements elements = doc.select("body > *:not(img)");
final Iterator<Element> iterator = elements.iterator();
final StringBuilder finalContent = new StringBuilder();

Element current;
while (iterator.hasNext() && !(current = iterator.next()).tagName().startsWith("a")) {
    finalContent.append(current.toString());
    String siblingText = current.nextSibling().attr("text").trim();
    if (!siblingText.isEmpty()) {
        finalContent.append(siblingText);
    }
}

System.out.println(finalContent);
```

Firstly we select all elements excluding `<img>` with selector `body > *:not(img)`. Then we iterate over all elements until we reach the end of the list or we reach first `a` element. We also check if there is a sibling text node containing any content - this is a case for a phone number since it is not placed inside any HTML tag and it's a sibling to one of the `<br>` tags.

Running this example generates following output:

```
 <p>hello,<br>&nbsp;<br>We need to dispatch the below documents to you. Thanks for your cooperation.<br><br>Best Regards</p><br><br><b>Test_firstname90 Test_lastname90</b><br><br>T +91 98 471<br>
```

Of course you define different iteration stop rule, this example was created to give you a hint. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Szymon.. I am working on this .. Meanwhile The output I require also has a phone number at the end which does not come in the snippet you share .. Also all img tags have to be removed in the entire snippet ..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the snippet a little bit to remove all `img` tags and find a text node holding phone number.

Comment: Thanks a lot Szymon .. One question .. In place of "a" if I have some comment like <!-- My Comment text -->  and I would like to delete all text after that comment. Can you share something for this..  This comment would be static in most of the cases ..

Comment: @Teena you may try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941080/2194470  It's not exact same case, but it explains how to get HTML comments with Jsoup

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this